# Is there a way to skip Swift XCTestCase for the whole class

Tags: swift, xctest, xctestcase

In a Swift XCTestCase, I'm looking for a way to:

1. Run function during setup and teardown, once per class that may throw error
2. Skip all the test functions within that one class if the above setup throws error

I found that one way to skip test is to `throw XCTSkip()`.  I can do this within the test function or within `func setUpWithError() throws`.  But I can't do this inside `class func setUp()` nor `class func tearDown()`.

Here's an example:

```
class TestClassOne: XCTestCase {
    override class func setUp() {
        // If this fails, I would like to skip tests 1 and 2 but not 3 and 4
        try settingUpForAllTestsInThisClass() // not allowed: setUp doesn't throw
    }

    override class func tearDown() {
        try tearingDownForAllTestsInThisClass() // not allowed: tearDown doesn't throw
    }

    func test1() {
        // Do something that depends on the one time class setup
    }

    func test2() {
        // Do something that depends on the one time class setup
    }
}

class TestClassTwo: XCTestCase {
    override class func setUp() {
        // If this fails, I would like to skip tests 3 and 4 but not 1 and 2
        try settingUpSomethingElseForAllTestsInThisClass() // not allowed: setUp doesn't throw
    }

    override class func tearDown() {
        try tearingDownSomethingElseForAllTestsInThisClass() // not allowed: tearDown doesn't throw
    }

    func test3() {
        // Do something that depends on the one time class setup
    }

    func test4() {
        // Do something that depends on the one time class setup
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you might be able to achieve this with a custom subclass of `XCTestSuite` which overrides [`perform(_:)`](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-xctest/blob/ea5c74d5f024c1e024d035e887c7debfbb26cfea/Sources/XCTest/Public/XCTestSuite.swift#L41-L54)

Answer (score 1):

You could catch the error in `class func setUp()` and use the result to fail the test in `func setUpWithError()`:

```swift
class TestClassOne: XCTestCase {
    static var setupFailed = false

    override class func setUp() {
        do {
            try settingUpForAllTestsInThisClass()
        } catch {
            setupFailed = true
        }
    }

    override func setUpWithError() throws {
        if Self.setupFailed {
            XCTFail()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was just talking to a colleague and we ended up with the same solution.